# Busca em todo site

Tags: php, mysql, query, algoritmo-de-busca

É muito comum encontrar em sites uma busca que retorna registros de tabelas distintas.

Preciso implementar em meu site uma busca que retorne `produtos` e `usuários`(perfil) cadastrados no site. O resultado deve ser misturar, porém o link para os mesmos serão diferentes, ex: `site.com/perfil/id` e `site.com/produto/id`.

Vou precisar de duas *querys*? Ou apenas com uma consulta consigo esse resultado?

Não poderei usar `JOIN` já que minhas tabelas não têm relação.
Espero que eu tenha sido claro.

Comment: Eu diria que era melhor fazer das pesquisas separadas e mostrar na tabela de resultados (se for uma tabela) os resultados com o link próprio.

Comment: Jorge, não existe a tabela resultados, o mesmo é o retorno(escrever em tela) da consulta das duas tabelas.

Comment: Eu estava a falar de uma `table` do HTML mas pode ser outra coisa qualquer.

Comment: Dessa maneira o resultado não virá misturado, certo? terei em primeiro momento a lista de todos os produtos encontrados e depois todos o usuários encontrados?

Comment: Sim basicamente é isso.

Comment: Suas tabelas são iguais, com os mesmos campos? `produto.id, produto.nome`, `usuario.id, usuario.nome`...? Caso seja, você pode usar `UNION ALL`

Comment: @PapaCharlie mas isso não vai dar asneira? depois como é que ele sabe a que pesquisa se liga a que tabela?

Comment: @JorgeB. Creio que não, eu faria: query-1 `concat("user") as 'tipo'`, query-2 `concat("product") as 'tipo'`, assim temos a referencia do tipo de tabela.

Comment: @PapaCharlie faz uma resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB., mas depende da estrutura da tabela dele. Mas vou elaborar uma resposta simples por aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Você pode usar [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) para combinar os resultados da sua consulta.
>
> UNION é usado para combinar o resultado de vários SELECT's em um único conjunto de resultados.

```
( select nome, concat( "U" ) as `tipo` from user    where nome = ? ) union all
( select nome, concat( "P" ) as `tipo` from product where nome = ? )
```

A query acima monta vai buscar nas tabelas `user` e `product`, todos registros que contiverem o *termo* buscado no nome.

Suas tabelas podem ter uma estrutura diferente: `user.idade`, `user.sobrenome`, `product.preco`... mas a instrução `UNION` precisa da mesmas quantidade de campos.

Se sua necessidade é exibir os nomes como resultado de uma pesquisa, creio que `UNION` seja uma alternativa viável.

No caso usei `concat( "X" ) as 'tipo'`, onde *tipo* representa o tipo de tabela. Quando fizer a listagem, basta fazer a comparação para inserir o link de acordo.

```
if( $row['tipo'] = 'U' )
{
   // link para usuário
}
else
{
   // link para produto
}
```

Comment: Perfeito @Papa Charlie, atendeu a minha necessidade, estudarei mais sobre o UNION.

Comment: @Dagobe se possível, coloque a estrutura das suas tabelas.

Comment: o `SELECT` funcionou, você quer que eu poste o script `SQL`? E sou novo por aqui e não consegui postar pela quantidade de caracteres que possui a estrutura. Como faço para postar?

Comment: @Dagobe, não precisa ser tudo, apenas os campos da tabela... Mas se funcionou de acordo, então creio que não haja necessidade por mim.

Comment: Obrigado @Papa, marquei sua resposta como a que me atendeu.